# How to write Core Data fetch request on complex fetch count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to figure out how to write the following SQL in the form of the Core Data fetch statements:

```
select count(*) from MYTABLE where MYTABLE.size='2';
```

All I have at the moment is the following:

```
//setup predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == %@", @"size",     searchInteger];
[request setPredicate:predicate];


NSError *error = nil; 
NSInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
NSLog(@"fetch results count = %i", count);
[request release];
```

What I am not sure of is:

1. Is this the most efficient / speedy way to do a select count(*) with a condition
2. Is there any other way to setup the predicate here to be more efficient?

Any suggestions from the gurus welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Pras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `countForFetchRequest:` is certainly the most efficient way to get the count. I would think that you should **not** use the keyword `ANY` in your predicate format string, though.

Also, make sure that your `searchInteger` is of type `NSNumber`. If not you need to wrap it into something like `[NSNumber numberWithInt:searchInteger]`.

Comment: Thanks Mundi. I will use countForFetch as stated. In terms of the searchInteger, it is actually a NSString value on the database, so I need to search for a string rather than NSNumber